# C# вложеные класы

Tags: c#, классы, наследование

Существуют два класа : один дочерний, второй родительский

```
 class foo
 {

    protected class Quux
    {
      public Quux()
      {
      Console.WriteLine("Foo.Quux()");
      } 
    }

 }

  class bar:foo
  {
    new class Quux
    {
        public Quux()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux()");
        }
    }
  }
```

В функции main вот такой код:

```
static void main() 
 {
    new bar();

 }
```

Не могу понять определения внутренего класа в дочернем класе. Зачем написано new и как будет ввести себя программа. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: какая программа? уберите `new` и посмотрите.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл написать, что в main вот такой код     new Bar();

Comment: код не скомпилируется - нет класса `Bar`

Comment: этот код ничего не делает, кроме создания одного объекта типа `bar`

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Но почему в дочернем классе при объявлении внутренего класа Quux написано оператор new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без `new` компилятор выдаст предупреждение, что `bar.Quux` перекрывает/прячет `foo.Quux`, а написав `new`, программист говорит компилятору, что это делается специально, чтобы компилятор не волновался.